# Get css value without DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering if there is a way to get css value from stylesheet file when there is no element in the DOM using it? I am using jQuery and I use selector $(".classname").css() to get the values. But with the case "classname" is not in any element, what to do to get the value" Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just create an element with that class name and inspect it. You don't even need to attach it to the DOM:

```
var $el = $('<div class="classname"></div>');
var opacity = $el.css('opacity') // or whatever
```

Even though `$el` is not actually present in the DOM, you still get access to all of its style properties.

---

*Edit*: as mentioned in the comments, this approach does not always work as expected (eg  [inherited css values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/inheritance) not defined on .classname explicitly, [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity) above .classname, etc).

For example the following fails due to `#foo` increasing the selector specificity beyond that of a standalone `.bar`:

css:

```
#foo .bar { color: red; }
```

js:

```
var $el = $('<div class="bar"></div>');
$el.css('color'); // Expected: "red", Actual: ""
```

Comment: What about inherited styles? I'm assuming you could use something like `$('<div id="foo"><div class="classname"></div></div>').find('.classname').css('opacity')`, but there are plenty of cases where even that would break down (e.g. styles inherited from specific selectors on `html` or `body`).

Comment: The element must be in the DOM to get the styles. JQuery probably doing it anyway. with Vanilla JS is not working and you get no styles.

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript which presents a cross-browser approach to getting and adding css dynamically.

It works with `document.styleSheets` and both IE's `.rules` and everyone else's `.cssRules`

It also has the advantage of being somewhat abstracted so you don't need to worry about the details.

---

The above link no longer works. The following is a screenshot of the blog-article, captured by the internet archive wayback in 2008.

[image]

The function basically iterates over all styles of all stylesheets and provides the ability to modify / delete them.
**Please note** that this cannot be recommended, since most modern stylesheets are too large to make this an efficient operation.

Comment: And so another answer in stack overflow falls to link decay :(

Answer (score 2):

You could go (this also works in chrome):

```
var $elem = $('<div id="foo"></div>').appendTo('body'),
    value = $elem.css('margin-top');

$('#foo').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the styles from [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets).

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the Chromium problem, you need to add it to the body:

Sample CSS:

```
.dummy {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

Sample Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dummy = $('<div class="dummy" style="display: none;"></div>').appendTo('body');
  console.log(dummy.css("min-width"));
  console.log(dummy.css("max-width"));
  dummy.remove();
});
```

This works on all modern browsers, Chrome, FF, IE11.